# Get english alphabet as String

Tags: string, groovy, alphabet

I recently started learning Groovy.
My task is to get english alphabet.
I don't understand, why code

```
println 'a'..'z'
```

working fine, but when i try to get it class

```
println 'a'..'z'.class
```

ClassCastException occures.
I want to do something like this:

```
return 'a'..'z'.toString()
```

Can u help me? What is best way to get english alphabet in String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
groovy:000> println(('a'..'z').class)
class groovy.lang.ObjectRange
```

It boils down to parsing issues.

```
'a'..'z'.class
```

is interpreted as meaning "From `'a'` to `'z'.class`".

You can't write

```
println ('a'..'z').class
```

because that would be trying to call `class` on the return of `println`, which doesn't return anything.

The quickest way to get this as a string is simply:

```
('a'..'z').join()
```

Answer (score 3):

> My task is to get english alphabet.

I'm not sure exactly what structure you want to store these letters in, here's an example that demonstrates how to store them in a `List` and a single `String`

```
List alphabet = ('a'..'z').collect { it }
String letters = ('a'..'z').join()
```